# What is the best electrical box for stucco wall

Tags: electrical, receptacle

We added a 3-season room, which used to be a covered patio before. I am currently doing rough electrical work. Plan to add 6 electrical boxes to bring it to the code.

Two outlets went to the new wall with a. That was pretty straightforward. I started working to add outlets to the existing stucco wall. The thickness of the wall is 1-1/4".

Originally I was planning to use an old-work electrical box. However, because of the thickness of the wall, I realized the flaps could not engage.

Then I tried using a shallow electrical box, but as I was not sure about whether I'll have enough space to put the receptacle in, I removed that.

Finally, I took the flap out for the old-work electrical box and screwed that into the plywood sheath using 1-5/8" screws. It is sturdy now. However, I am still not very satisfied with the result.

So, the question is when faced with similar situation what electrical box did you use?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What I do when there's an issue with thickness of the wall for an old-work box is that
I make sure that the outlet is going to be up against a stud in the edge of the plaster. The stucco needs to be cut exactly flush with the stud. Then I use an old-work box because of the need to have a clamp in it and I put it in the opening with a very generous layer of construction adhesive against the stud and push it over and force it to be solidly glued and let it sit overnight. You're going to have to make a real effort if you want to get that box off and it's good to go without the little plastic don't want to hold me tabs.

Comment: Welcome to [diy.se]! There were some typos in this answer that made it somewhat difficult to understand. I've edited to the best of my ability, and I think this represents what you were trying to say. If I've missed something, please feel free to [edit] again to make additional corrections. I must ask, though - it's my understanding that all UL-listed devices must be installed in accordance with their manufacturer's instructions to maintain their UL listing. Do your old-work boxes list "construction adhesive to the stud" as an acceptable installation method?